# Changing font size in whiptail dialog boxes

Tags: whiptail

I've made script using a few different whiptail boxes, which all work fine, but I'd like the font size to be larger.  All my google searches on *whiptail font size* tell me either about whiptail box sizes, or about font sizes not related to whiptail.  And nothing on the man page.  Is there a way to change the whiptail font size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No font options listed on the man page was a clue.
You just need to increase the font size on the terminal window in which the whiptail script is being run.  Whiptail uses that font.